# Unable to change integer in QString

Tags: qt

I have a `QString strLayout` which has value `"3,1,0"`.

I want to change it to "**2,1,0**".

So I extracted the first character, converted to number and subtracted 1 from it:

```
int temp = (strLayout.at(0).digitValue() - 1);
```

Now, I want it to write back to original `QString strLayout` as follows:

```
strLayout[0] = temp;
```

The problem is that this does not replace the first character to `2`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `not able to do it` Why? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: Please read documents: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-8`strLayout.replace(strLayout.split(',').at(0), QString::number(strLayout.at(0).digitValue() - 1));`

Comment: strLayout[0] = temp;

Comment: Don't comment. Put it in the question. What did you try to do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: Thank you @IMAN4K for pointing me to the documentation. I will try understanding the code there. Your solution worked for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the difference between the number `2` and the character `'2'`, which corresponds with `50` according to the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) encoding.

`strLayout[0] = temp;` will reinterpret the number `temp` (`2`) as the character that is encoded as `2`, i.e. the special character to indicate the [`Start of Text`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX).

Three solutions exist:

- Convert integer back to a string:

  ```
  strLayout[0] = QString::number(temp)[0];
  ```
- Do not convert your character to an integer:

  ```
  strLayout[0] = strLayout.at(0) - 1;
  ```

  This trick works because the ASCII character set encodes numbers to a continuous maintaining its normal order (the numbers `0-9` corresponds with `48-57` ASCII values)
- Convert integer back to a character

  ```
  strLayout[0] = temp + '0';
  ```

  This adds to the integer `temp` the ASCII value of the number `0`